# How can I make a request of a UserController in TitleController CakePHP?

Tags: cakephp

How can I make a request of a UserController in TitleController in CakePHP?

I try

```
$ this-> User-> Title-> find ('list');
```

but it does not work.

Comment: That's not really the way MVC is designed to work. If you want to execute a common task, add it to your `AppController` as a protected method. Can you explain what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: How to make a request in AppController?
Can a small example, please.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do here. Are you trying to access data from a table in a database? Do you just want to perform some logic in your UsersController? You need to be more specific in your question because you can't make a request from one controller to another (without redirecting the client). Perhaps you're talking Models in Controllers?

Comment: I trying to access data from a table in a database. I have a dynamic left menu (element), and not to make inquiries is constantly in every method() I want to make a request in AppController. But I do not know how to make a database query from the AppController and AppModel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there is a relationship such as HasMany or BelongsTo between your User model and your Title model, you will be able to make your piece of code work. If there is no relationship, you will need to load the model first :

In your Title controller :

```
$this->loadModel('User');
$this->User->find('list');
```

Comment: Thanks, I would like, made ​​the request in AppController.
    public function beforeFilter() {
        parent::beforeFilter();

        $this->loadModel('Title');
        $titles = $this->Title->find('list');
        $this->set(compact('titles')); 

}